# Disabled Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I basically have a couple of checkboxes in my form, that are not database items but am retrieving the source value based on a database column.

As I do not want the user to be able to change these checboxes, I have disabled these checkboxes.

When I query a record, the form at start-up retrieves the value for the checkbox with no issues.

The problem is, when I hit a validation error on my form when the page is submitted, my checkbox values that were originally retrieved as 'Y', i.e checked are now null.

How can I maintain these values when a validation error occurs?

Comment: I take it you have validations on disabled checkboxes? Why not remove or disable the validations?

Comment: No validations on disabled checkboxes. All I use the disabled checkboxes is for a workflow indicator so that the user knows when a step was performed and so, show the disabled item as checked.

Answer (score 1):

A disabled control will not be successful (that's the point of `disabled`).

Either go with a `readonly` control instead, or use a `hidden` input.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a hidden input checkbox - thanks.

Comment: A "hidden input" not a "hidden input checkbox". `<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar">`

Comment: Thanks David but based on this, how can I maintain the value of the checkboxes after a validation failure due to some other field requiring an input? I basically need to get the checkbox to the state it was prior to validation failure.

Comment: I have no idea how your system is structured. So I don't know how you could find out that previous value.

Comment: No worries David - appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the checkboxes in question just before you post the form. Then they will be "just sent back", (hopefully) untouched.

As always, you must do your server side checks and not expect that form values and/or javascript have not been tampered with.